# Tokens and wildcards in for loops

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a txt file called "index" which contains a list of the names of a set of files. The files follow the same naming format: 01 - aaa; 02 - bbb; 03 - ccc etc where the letters represent whatever the name of the file is. I want to create a txt file with the names as follows:

aaa

bbb

ccc

i.e removing the numbers, hyphen and extension in a vertical list which I can then copy elsewhere.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3* delims= " %%g in ('dir /b /o:n') do (
    if not %%~nxg==index.bat (
        echo %%g >> index.txt
    )
)
endlocal
```

This correctly loops through the files and ignores index.bat (which is the file I'm running) but it outputs the third token only and not all subsequent tokens. The * wildcard should mean it outputs the entire rest of the string but it doesn't seem to work?

Any other general improvements would be appreciated - only been learning batch for a week or so.

EDIT: Magoo and npocmaka's answers below solved it. %%h contains the wildcard information. `"tokens=2* delims= "` will assign the 2nd token to %%g and the 3rd + the rest to %%h.

The working code is as follows:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%g in ('dir /b /o:n') do (
    if not %%~nxg==%%~nx0 (
        set name=%%h
        echo !name:~0,-4! >> index.txt
    )
)
endlocal
```

`if not %%~nxg==%%~nx0` excludes the batch file from the loop, `set name=%%h` creates a new variable so that I can do a substring to remove the extension. `echo !name:~0,-4!` is the substring and it selects the entire string except the last 4 characters so as to exclude the file extension and then `>> index.txt` creates a new text file in the same directory with only the required characters.

Comment: `*` is a separate token. you can try with `echo %%g %%h`

Comment: You should have powershell installed by default, that would be a lot easier!

Comment: @npocmaka what would that output. Sorry, away from my PC today so can't check how it works. What would the value of %%h be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `%%h` would contain the remainder of the line.

You might consider changing to `tokens=2*` when `%%h` would contain the 3rd and later tokens.

You may want to add `/a-d` into the `dir` to ignore any directorynames encountered.

Comment: How do I use the value of %%h? Can I just echo it having set %%g in the for loop? Sorry, basic question I know. I'm still learning.

Comment: The syntax `tokens=3* ... %%g` means "assign token 3 to `%%g` and the rest of the line after token 3 to `%%h`" If you use `tokens=1,2,3 ... %%a` then token 1 is assigned to `%%a`, 2 to `%%b` and 3 to `%%c`. `%%h` would be established by your original code because the selected metavariable `%%g` has the lowest token number assigned, then each selected token from the tokens list is assigned to the next-metavariable alphabetically. The tokens list must contain a separator like `,` if it may be misinterpreted. For instance `12*` may mean 1,2 and * or 12 and *, so 1,2* is required for the second

Comment: Thanks, this works! 

For future reference and for anyone coming to this question later my working code is an edit in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, just change:

```
"tokens=2* delims=-"
```

If you can only use pre-installed apps, this is a nice powershell one liner:

```
gci C:\folder -Exclude "index" | % {($_ -split "-")[1]} | out-file C:\index.txt
```

It may need modifying depending on your needs though.

Comment: Could you try it with a file name with multiple words? I.e "tokens=3* delims= " on the file name "01 - a a a". There are multiple tokens after the hyphen and the * wildcard does not seem to capture them for me. Thanks.